# R Programming- Need to calculate upto three most common values of an attribute in sorted order

Tags: r

I have a column

```
Yes_No
-------
No
No
Yes
Yes
Yes
No
No
Yes
Yes
No
No
No
Yes
```

Then output should be

```
MCV
----------
No(7) Yes(6)
```

If the data is

```
Yes_No
-------
No
No
Yes
Yes
Yes
MayBe
No
Yes
Yes
No
MayBe
No
Yes
```

Then

```
MCV
--------
Yes(6) No(5) Maybe(2)
```

Comment: try `table(data$Yes_No)` and may needs some formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you can see, not having a reproducible example can call the hounds on you. Nevertheless, I feel that your problem was well-described, if not well researched, and thus deserves an answer (if not too time consuming). In this case, there are some basic data manipulation functions that you will have to familiarize yourself with. The `cat`function will allow you to return a text report with the results. Here is an example:

```
# make data
df <- data.frame(Yes_No = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 10, replace=TRUE))
df

# convert "Yes_No" to factor
df$Yes_No <- factor(df$Yes_No, levels=c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"))

# summary
summary(df)

# or aggregate
res <- aggregate(df, by=list(df$Yes_No), FUN=length)
res
cat(" MCV\n", "--------------\n", paste(res[,1], " (", res[,2], ")", sep="", collapse=" "))

# MCV
# --------------
# Yes (7) No (3)

##### ALT w/ "Maybe" ###
df <- data.frame(Yes_No = sample(c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"), 20, replace=TRUE))
df$Yes_No <- factor(df$Yes_No, levels=c("Yes", "No", "Maybe"))
res <- aggregate(df, by=list(df$Yes_No), FUN=length)
res
cat(" MCV\n", "--------------\n", paste(res[,1], " (", res[,2], ")", sep="", collapse=" "))
# MCV
# --------------
# Yes (9) No (6) Maybe (5)
```

Comment: How can I restrict the output only to three most common values. For example if my data had another value say "Other" . so in total 4 values Yes,No,Maybe and Other. My output should still show only Yes (9) No (6) Maybe (5)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a table.

```
table(dataframe$columnname)
```